# MKMapView didUpdateUserLocation not updating

Tags: iphone, mkmapview, userlocation

I have an application with map and want to zoom to the current location, when it's updated.

I use `-(void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation` delegate method to know when user location was updated.

Now on simulator method is being called as it should. But when i test it on device (iphone 2g) the location is updated on map, but "didUpdateUserLocation" method is not being called at all, same for delegate method "mapViewWillStartLocatingUser".

The system asks if I allow to get my location for app and starts showing my location, but

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
NSLog(@"didUpdateUserLocation = '%@'", userLocation);
```

}

is never called.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Reference mentions that this delegate method is available since iOS 4.0. Your simulator is most probably running iOS 4.0 while your phone - iOS 3.1.

I'm having the same problem and still looking for solution. Perhaps accessing CL methods directly will help.

Comment: Thank you! I never thought that checking that.

Comment: I'm glad I helped. I solved the problem by quering for user location every second or so. If you find a better solution I'd appreciate you posting it here :)

Answer (score 0):

try this Map.showsUserLocation=YES;